# Unable to locate Dependency selenium-webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, nuget, visual-studio-code, dnu

I've created ASP .Net console project in Visual Studio Code (OS X).

Then added the dependency in project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "selenium-webdriver": "2.52.0"
},
```

Run "dnu restore" and getting an error:

> Microsoft .NET Development Utility CoreClr-x64-1.0.0-rc1-16231
>
> CACHE api.nuget.org/v3/index.json Restoring packages for
>   /Users/user/Code/ConsoleApplication/project.json
>
> GET api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/selenium-webdriver/index.json
>
> NotFound api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/selenium-webdriver/index.json
>   2432ms
>
> Unable to locate Dependency selenium-webdriver >= 2.52.0
>   Writing lock file
>   /Users/user/Code/ConsoleApplication/project.lock.json Restore
>   complete, 3027ms elapsed
>
> Errors in /Users/user/Code/ConsoleApplication/project.json
>       Unable to locate Dependency selenium-webdriver >= 2.52.0
>
> Feeds used:
>       https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer is simple - typo. The id is `selenium.webdriver`, not the `selenium-webdriver`